# What can cause viscosity in a BEC gas?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, viscosity, bose-einstein-condensate

I know that Bose-Einstein condensate is not always a superfluid. So what can cause viscosity in a BEC gas?

Comment: This might help - [Does every superfluid have a normal and a superfluid component?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/311115/37364)

Comment: A Galilean BEC (by which I mean a BEC of massive bosons whose kinetic energy $\sim p^2$) has quadratically dispersing low energy excitations, whereas a superfluid has linearly dispersing excitations. The linear dispersion in superfluids is _crucial_ to zero viscosity -- see Landau's [ingenious argument](https://www.nii.ac.jp/qis/first-quantum/e/forStudents/lecture/pdf/qis385/QIS385_chap5.pdf), discussed in most references on the topic .